# How to use AVspeechSynthesizer for phonics sounds of alphabets

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, avspeechsynthesizer

Can I use `AVspeechSynthesizer` for phonics sounds of alphabets? If yes can any one help me to achieve this? If no please let me know is there any other ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a late reply but think to answer it. As it may help others.

As you ask for Phonic Sounds of alphabet it is not available in iOS. AVspeechSynthesizer can’t do this for you.You have to write the algorithm to detect phoneme from the text and process it further according to your requirement.